# Why is the character in video is blurry when rending video by d3d9

Tags: ffmpeg, direct3d

I use the following code to render video:

```
IDirect3DSurface9* surface = (IDirect3DSurface9*)frame->data[3];
        IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice = (IDirect3DDevice9*)(((DXVA2DevicePriv*)((AVHWDeviceContext*)hw_device_ctx->data)->user_opaque)->d3d9device);
        pDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
        pDevice->BeginScene();
        CComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9> back_buffer;

        HRESULT hr = pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &back_buffer);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            //RTC_LOG(LS_ERROR) << "Failed to get back buffer" << (int)hr;
            return -1;
        }

        if (surface != nullptr) {
            hr = pDevice->StretchRect(surface, nullptr, back_buffer, nullptr, D3DTEXF_POINT);
            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                
                return -1;
            }
        }

        pDevice->EndScene();
        
        hr = pDevice->Present(nullptr, nullptr, hWnd, nullptr);
```

I don't know why the character in the video is blurry, but the image seems be better.
Is there any settings to set to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make a screenshot, compare with a screenshot of a known good player like VLC or MPC-HC.

If MPC-HC will be equally blurry, the settings you should adjust is the encoder ones. For one you could try a video encoded into High 4:4:4 h.264 profile, the version without chroma downsampling i.e. 4:4:4 format.

If MPC-HC is not blurry but your code is, might be an issue on your side. Most probable cause is the StretchRect.

BTW, on modern Windows, the correct way to render a hardware-decoded video is D3D11 and [IMFMediaEngine API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfmediaengine/nf-mfmediaengine-imfmediaengineclassfactory-createinstance) in the default, frame-server, mode. Don't forget to set the `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_DXGI_MANAGER` attribute. If you have to integrate with D3D9 e.g. because WPF, use D3D11 to render video into a RGBA8 texture created by IDirect3DDevice9.CreateTexture and imported into D3D11 with ID3D11Device.OpenSharedResource. You should resize the video only once, using the arguments of [TransferVideoFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfmediaengine/nf-mfmediaengine-imfmediaengine-transfervideoframe) method.